# Unable to add New Page in SharePoint online Pages library

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am using the SharePoint Online team site. I need to add new pages in the SharePoint Pages library when I click on the New button **Page** option is missing in the menu.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvidd.png) to check the current options which I have shown while clicking on the New button.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to library settings -> Check whether it has Page content type. If it does not have, please add the Page content type.

2.Click Edit new menu -> Check whether you could add the Page content type.